# How to update a object that contains a collection of other objects in c# in ado.net?

Tags: c#, ado.net, domain-driven-design, repository

I have a customer entity. My customer entity has a collection of address value objects that pertain to my given entity. If a customer adds a new address, how will my repository know which address is the new one to add when I pass it back to the repository to update? I'm using plain ado.net.

```
public class Customer
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public bool Update(Customer customer)
    {
        //Update logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework or raw ADO.NET?

Comment: Snapshotting. Compare state before and after performing state changes and derive intent (bad, but your choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is that it's something complicated and that's why one should use an ORM (EntityFramework, NHibernate, etc.) instead of reinventing the wheel.

The most easy thing I think you can do is to make your entities implement INotifyPropertyChanged and make your repository suscribe to the PropertyChanged. Than, you can have a track of the object that have changed and their properties, so you will be able to create the needed updates as well.

Also, if your collection is an ObservableCollection you will be able to track if an item was added (and make the proper insert) of if some object was removed (and make the proper delete or update if it was moved to another object, depending on the logic you expect).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Value objects are immutable meaning that when you update a value object you need to remove it then add the updated one.

as the identity of value object does not exist then you will have to remove all addresses for your entity/aggregate root (Customer) then add them again.

if your value objects are very large then this may be an indicator that it should not be a value object and be an entity instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track the state of the collection of Addresses. You might use a per-record flag to indicate that the record was inserted or updated.

Alternatively, you can use a DataSet rather than a List<>. DataSet includes support for change tracking, which you can tie back to ADO.NET (for example, using a SqlDataAdapter).